# Проблема с переносом сайта на Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Перёнес сайт на движке Битрикс с одного хостинга на другой, при загрузки не выдаёт ошибок вообще нигде, логи пустые, грузит сайт все CSS и JS а сам контент не загружается.

Кто может подсказать в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Возможно стоит сбросить кэш. Если есть возможность, дайте ссылку на сайт.

Comment: На джумле бывает после переноса такой глюк. 
Открываем папку с файлами сайта, запускаем какой-нибудь текстовый редактор с поиском по папкам. Пишем туда старый домен и жмем искать. Если находятся упоминания старого домена - меняем их на новый. Все работает.
Но это я так джумлу переносил без всяких скриптов миграции. Попробуйте, а вдруг поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DmitryS. Спасибо разобрался была проблема в мускуле, dbconn.php в редакторе было норм, а открыл через nano он пуст. и ещё 1 таблица не перенеслась + в php.ini были выключенны short_open_tag, так же SymLinks php больше не поддерживат. СТранно почему apache log не выводил будем искать, всем спасибо..